# Non used JS function interferes with actual HTML/JS/Babel code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

On the code below I expected that (console logged) object `props` only contains member: `className` but it contains members: `{ className, id, ticket, request }`. However, if I remove param `...others` from **non used function**: `NullComp`, then the only member of object `props` is: `className`, which is what I was expecting initially.

You can try it by yourself by running the code below:

with: `...others`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    function GoalComp({
      id,
      ticket,
      request,
      ...props
    }) {
      console.log(props);
      return <div>Independent Retriever</div>;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    function NullComp({ timeRanges, ...others }) {
      return null;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const { useState, useEffect } = React;
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <GoalComp
          className="mt-10"
          id="1"
          ticket="IT-ABCD"
          request="Peace and Love"
        />
      );
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

without: `...others`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script type="text/babel">
    function GoalComp({
      id,
      ticket,
      request,
      ...props
    }) {
      console.log(props);
      return <div>Independent Retriever</div>;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    function NullComp({ timeRanges }) {
      return null;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel">
    const { useState, useEffect } = React;
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <GoalComp
          className="mt-10"
          id="1"
          ticket="IT-ABCD"
          request="Peace and Love"
        />
      );
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I'm I missing here?

Comment: Don't use multiple `<script/>` tags, ..

Comment: @Keith, using a single <script> tag does address the issue in the minimal working example (MWE) provided above. However, it's crucial to remember that this is just an MWE. In my actual setup, the code is divided across multiple files, for instance, two files. That's the reason I originally had two <script> tags. Therefore, merging the code into one <script> tag doesn't genuinely resolve my problem.

Comment: Please note:  babel standalone is really not meant for production, each script tag is going to be a separate compile, I'm actually surprised it works at all here, as compilers generally have a lot of internal state / cache etc to cater for.  It will be this cache / state that's getting mixed up between script tags.  If you really want to continue to use babel standalone, and you want to share functions, place the function into a browser global, this will then bypass the internal state of each function.  Of course the best option is to use babel inside a build system like webpack / vite etc.

Comment: @Keith I tried by using: `window.GoalComp = function(...) {...}`, `window.NullComp = function(...) {...}` and `<window.GoalComp ... />` but got same effect. Do you think is there any workaround for this where I could split the code into multiple `<script />` tags or I don't have any option at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using babel standalone is really not meant for production.

But out of curiosity I thought it would be fun to see why this breaks.

If you compile `GoalComp` in babel, for a target that doesn't support spread syntax, you will notice it creates a global ->

```
var _excluded = ["id", "ticket", "request"];
```

On the other hand if you compiled both `GoalComp` & `NullComp` with the spread operators together you will get ->

```
var _excluded = ["id", "ticket", "request"],
  _excluded2 = ["timeRanges"];
```

But if you do them as separate scripts/compiles.

You would end up with.

```
var _excluded = ["id", "ticket", "request"],
var _excluded = ["timeRanges"];
```

To get around this you could place the functions on a global, but you will also need to set the scripts `data-type="module"` to keep those `_excluded` scoped locally.

eg.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="root"></div>
  <script>
    //somewhere to store the functions
    const GF = {};
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel" data-type="module">
    function GoalComp({
      id,
      ticket,
      request,
      ...props
    }) {
      console.log(props);
      return <div>Independent Retriever</div>;
    }
    GF.GoalComp = GoalComp;
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel" data-type="module">
    function NullComp({ timeRanges, ...others }) {
      return null;
    }
  </script>
  <script type="text/babel" data-type="module">
    const { useState, useEffect } = React;
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <GF.GoalComp
          className="mt-10"
          id="1"
          ticket="IT-ABCD"
          request="Peace and Love"
        />
      );
    };
    ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```